# Can't click on start button and programs in taskbar

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, rds

I have several users using RDS to my Windows Server 2012 R2.

Only one of my users have this problem...

He can't click the start button. If he hover the start button, it flickers.

Furthermore if he minimize apps, then he can't click them in the taskbar to restore the apps window state.

I have many user on the same box, but it is only 1 user having this problem.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this sometimes happen when there are two `explorer.exe` processes running. Open up Task Manager with `CTRL + Shift + Esc` and check if you currently have two explorer processes running.

Either way, a restart of the process should fix the issue. Just end the processes and start up a new one with `File > Run New Task`

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's a known issue for Microsoft and there are a lot of fixes for not functioning taskbar. Here is the step-by-step manual on how to fix it. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/fix-windows-10-taskbar-not-functioning/cc475554-e5a1-4e28-8444-83bd74a84bf7?tm=1438445987147

Answer (score 1):

We are running Windows Server 2016 RDSH, but maybe this will help you.

We hired a Windows wizard to help us and here is what he did:

Run the following on a command prompt as Administrator

```
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

Run the following on Powershell as Administrator

```
Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register “$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml”}
```

Apparently , the `Get-AppXPackage` command should be run after any new software installation. We didn't have the need yet, so can't confirm.

This solution has been working for us for more than 15 days, which is a record and we are very optimistic.

Comment: This worked for us on Server 2016. I got the message that Search couldn't be opened with the built-in Administrator account, though. It worked anyway where using `sfc /SCANNOW` did not.